# Form of art/work of art/ artwork/art forms

Tags: word-usage

Is my understanding of the words work of art, artworks, forms of art and art forms correct?

1. Mona Lisa is an artwork or a work of art.

"Dancing, singing, music, literature, poetry are works of art art forms or forms of art, but not artworks.
But Is Mona Lisa a form of art or an art form? I don't think so, but I may be wrong. It's a painting and that's a form of art or an art form but not the painting itself. The painting is a work of art or an artwork.

Answer (score 2):

I think you asked this question a fortnight ago. I will try to be clear.

The Mona Lisa is a painting. It is also a work of art.
The Mona Lisa is NOT an art form.
The Mona Lisa is NOT a 'form of art'.

You only need TWO expressions:

> 1 **Work of art:**
> The Mona Lisa is a work of art. It is **a painting**.
> Michelangelo's David is a work of art. It is a sculpture.
> Beethoven's symphonies are all works of art. They are pieces of music.
> Wordsworth's poems are works of art. They are poems.

> 2 **Art form:**
> These are all art forms: *ballet*, *painting*, *sculpture*, *music*, *poetry*. There are others.

I would advise you not to use "form of art". You don't need it. (I've never needed it.)
I would advise you to use the word "artwork" only when speaking about stuff made for  magazines, web sites, social media and pizza leaflets.

Comment: And cursed be any who carp!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so confused at first. Thus, The Mona Lisa or any other painting is a work of art or an artwork, David is a work of art or an artwork but not an art form. Music, literature, poetry, symphonies are works of art  and art forms but not artworks.

Comment: Yes, nearly! But a symphony is not an art form. Music is an art form. A symphony is a *piece of music*.

Comment: And remember - "artwork" is for pizza leaflets!